# Apache mod_auth_form causing internal server error 500

Tags: php, html, forms, apache, authentication

I've set my server to require authentication for all directories. I'm using Apache's mod_auth_form to generate an inline login form so as to preserve the HTTP_REQUEST so that the module can keep the user at whatever file/directory they had specified when being presented with the login form.

My issue is this: I navigate to the domain (example.com) and the login form is presented. Good. I login using incorrect credentials, login form shows again. Good. I enter correct credentials, get an Internal Server 500 error.

However, the weird thing that I don't understand is, if I were to visit a directory (example.com/images/) the login form is presented as it should be, and if I login, it correctly logs me in and shows the directory index of /images. This works with any subdirectory and even with any alias'd subdirectory I've created in http.conf.

The only time it messes up is just at the root/domain level. I'm lost.

Here's the relevant information from http.conf - let me know if any further information is needed.

```
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

--------------------------------------------------------

DocumentRoot "E:/"
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
# ======================================================
# !!! DO NOT CHANGE THIS LINE AND THE FOLLOWING ONES !!!
# DocumentRootDirectory 
<Directory "E:/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

--------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /images_easyphp "${path}/home/server_images"

    <Directory "${path}/home/server_images">
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "E:/">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AuthFormProvider file
        AuthType form
        AuthName "Restricted Access"
        Session On
        SessionCookieName session path=/
        require valid-user
        ErrorDocument 401 /WWW/login/index.php
        AuthUserFile "c:/server/apache/passwd"
    </Directory>

    <Directory "E:/WWW/login">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Location /logout>
        SetHandler form-logout-handler
        AuthFormLogoutLocation http://domain.com
        Session On
        SessionMaxAge 1
        SessionCookieName session path=/
    </Location>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "${path}/apache/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
```

Also worth mentioning, if I visit a subdirectory and successfully login, I can go back to root/domain level and it loads just fine with no 500 error.

Comment: Hmm. I think I found the issue - though I'm not sure why it would be an issue. The root has no index file, so it's just a directory. I added an index.php file. Now when I login at root level, it works and displays the index.php file. I'm not too sure why it wouldn't login and then display the directory?

Comment: So maybe you should change the question title to "Display the directory contents directly after mod_auth_form authorization"?